# How to implement a Angular 2+ step progress bar

Tags: html, angular, typescript, sass, progress-bar

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want to implement a 7 step progress bar in Angular2+ TypeScript+SCSS+HTML like shown in above image. I don't know how to proceed.

I have 7 steps(created, assigned, inprogress and so on) and three different paths (all 7 steps, blocked after 3 steps, rejected at initial step)

My thoughts:

1. Draw a line, add icons and then change icons once step is completed. should I use routing here?
2. add image/icons then add lines in between?
3. add default line, then add icons/images over it and colour the completed steps?

I am doing for a website so the words below the icons/images should resize accordingly and should work for phone size although not required at this point of time. Angular stepper has buttons and a bit complex for me. I am implementing in already existing website with internal calls for status variable. It will be placed in top right corner of the website.

Also it is ok to grey out 2 previous steps of current steps and showing next step in grey.

It's been quite confusing how to go about it, I am a very new to Angular2+.

Answer (score 0):

I did something somewhat similar awhile back, but ended up scrapping it so it is not super clean.  I also was just writing the name of the statuses and coloring them differently instead of having icons with labels underneath.  Mine would switch to a vertical view on small screen sizes.  Not sure if it will help much, but here's the html:

```
<div
    *ngIf="appeal && statuses && statuses.length > 0 && childVisible"
    fxLayout="row"
    fxLayoutAlign="start center"
    fxLayout.lt-md="column"
    class="py-24"
>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let status of statuses; let last = last; let index = index">
        <span [ngClass]="{ 'green-fg': index <= selection, 'orange-fg text-bold': index === selection }">{{
            status.statusDescription
        }}</span>
        <mat-divider
            fxHide.lt-md="true"
            fxHide="false"
            inset="true"
            fxFlex="1 0 15px"
            *ngIf="!last"
            class="my-0 mx-8"
        ></mat-divider>
        <mat-divider
            fxHide.lt-md="false"
            fxHide="true"
            vertical="true"
            inset="true"
            fxFlex="1 0 10px"
            *ngIf="!last"
            class="mx-0 my-4"
        ></mat-divider>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi i find a solution: this component call "stepper" in angular material have this solucion

example:
HTML

```
<button mat-raised-button (click)="isLinear = !isLinear" id="toggle-linear">
    {{!isLinear ? 'Enable linear mode' : 'Disable linear mode'}}
</button>
<mat-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
        <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
            <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
                <input matInput placeholder="Last name, First name" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
            </mat-form-field>
            <div>
                <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step [stepControl]="secondFormGroup" label="Fill out your address">
        <form [formGroup]="secondFormGroup">
            <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
                <mat-label>Address</mat-label>
                <input matInput formControlName="secondCtrl" placeholder="Ex. 1 Main St, New York, NY" required>
            </mat-form-field>
            <div>
                <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
                <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </mat-step>
    <mat-step>
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
        <p>You are now done.</p>
        <div>
            <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
            <button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </mat-step>
</mat-stepper>
```

ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

/**
 * @title Stepper overview
 */
@Component({
    selector: 'stepper-overview-example',
    templateUrl: 'stepper-overview-example.html',
    styleUrls: ['stepper-overview-example.css'],
})
export class StepperOverviewExample {
    firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
        firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
    });
    secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
        secondCtrl: ['', Validators.required],
    });
    isLinear = false;

    constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }
}
```

in here link find you the documentation here https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30768814)